# Mongo geo search $geoWithin not working with $and

Tags: mongodb

I have a basic source destination search for which i have 2 fields in my db. source_combo and destination_combo and i am trying to run this query .It's actually working for single field but when i am using $and the result is 0.

```
db.getCollection('trips').find({
  $and: [
    {
      destination_combo: {
        $geoWithin: {
          $centerSphere: [
            [23.688111, 86.950898],
            10 / 3963.2
          ]
        }
      }
    }, {
      source_combo: {
        $geoWithin: {
          $centerSphere: [
            [23.688111, 86.950898],
            10 / 3963.2
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

The basic requirement is i have a data whose "From location" and "To location"  should match. like while checking for flight source to destination.

The document looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "58fee3f5a8b566540e75c826",
    "destination_combo" : [ 
        {
            "lat" : 23.688111,
            "lon" : 86.950898,
            "_id" : ObjectId("58fee3f5a8b566540e75c827")
        }
    ],
    "source_combo" : [ 
        {
            "lat" : 23.688111,
            "lon" : 86.950898,
            "_id" : ObjectId("58fee3f5a8b566540e75c828")
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. Works find for me on v3.4.2. Add an example document you expect to be found.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Pdudxnev --- please check

Comment: Dear @nilasis-sen, it is recommended to put essential data to the question itself, rather than refer to 3rd party resources. Yet, I still cannot reproduce.

Comment: sorry for any inconvenience and @Alex thanks for the help my version was 2.* something so i upgraded it into v3.4.2 as you have used and it worked perfectly . thanks again .